# Hierarchical Tree-Based array/matrix indexing with cross-edges, does such a thing exist?

Tags: arrays, indexing, tree, multi-index

Hello esteemed StackOverflow community,

I am wondering if some type Hierarchical Tree-Based array/matrix indexing with cross-edges exists in the Data Structure literature, or if perhaps, this idea is over-complicating the issue.

To describe exactly what I am thinking: Imagine an array that holds the total inventory of animals at a zoo. Where each number represents the total number of specific animals

```
[ 1, 51, 32, 4, 7, 23, ...]
```

There could be a hierarchical tree-based classification that allows one to identify the animals to each number, or even just sum the category. This tree could be for example the animal taxonomy tree:

```
- Kingdom
  - Phylum
    - Class
      - Order
        - Family
          - Genus
            - Species
```

Where in pseudo code I could identify an animal:

```
array[animalia.chordata.mammalia.primates.homindae.pan.chimpanzee]
> 5
```

Or I could just get all apes or even all mammals:

```
array[animalia.chordata.mammalia.primates.homindae]
> [5, 9, 3, 2]
sum(array[animalia.chordata.mammalia.primates.homindae])
> 19
sum(array[animalia.chordata.mammalia])
> 152
```

I would like to extend this concept further by implementing cross-edges in a data structure, for example, a classification system involving food items:

```
- Food Types
  - Fruits
    - Apple
    - Banana
  - Vegetables
    - Carrot
    - Spinach
  - Dairy
    - Milk
    - Cheese
  - Grains
    - Rice
    - Wheat
  - Beverages
    - Water
    - Soda
    - Milk
```

With cross-edges, certain food items may appear in multiple categories. For instance, "Milk" could be classified both under "Dairy" and "Beverages." Given the cross-edges here, multi-indexing is not a viable option for the solution to this indexing structure. As Multi-indexing has to be MECE.

Perhaps the obvious answer is "No" because this data is best represented in a table data-structure. Therefore, no concept like this has been created.

However, such a data structure would be useful in some accounting practices where matrices of relational payments are made between different accounts. Perhaps this is done because it is more visually effective in Excel and it's never been done using code before. Nevertheless, if the indexes could be represented and sliced along either axis with the capabilities outlined above, it could be potentially useful for analysis. The analysis of this data relies on the matrix-like structure of payments between accounts. Therefore, containing the data in a long table-like format would make the analysis piece more difficult.

The primary issues I could see:

1. Insertion and deletion being complex and expensive operation
2. Aggregation being complex and expensive operation

#### Primary Questions

I would appreciate if anyone has any knowledge of a data structure that might exist or if there is a best practice for representing this data. Perhaps the solution is to keep the long-table format, filter, group and aggregate, then re-pivot back to the matrix format.

1. Does such a data-structure exist?
2. If not what would be the primary complications?
3. What is the best way to structure this data?

Would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree). This has an extra field that describes the number of nodes under the current node. While it takes an overhead of space and time to update, overall run-time complexity is the same, (but makes it easier to make an inconsistent tree.)

Commonly, order-static trees are made from [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) or other self-balancing trees, where operations can be performed in `log(n)` time. The Python module [blist](https://pypi.org/project/blist/) uses order statistic trees to improve `list` performance, but I don't know if this would be useful in your specific case.

What you are specifically describing is a tree with explicit fixed structure, in which case the `log(n)` guarantee would not necessarily hold. Also, the keys (animals) are all at the bottom, similar in structure to a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree). Your second example is a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) model; one generally has an intermediary structure that maps foods to tags, but it depends what one needs from the data.